# Can puspec.yaml update all grouped Xcode Targets?

Tags: flutter, fastlane

Along with my Flutter application I have an **Notification extension target**, which is associated with my main target by an **App Group**, this works fine as long as I manually update the non main target version to match the main target version.

If I don't I get a mismatched version error and the App store rejects the build.

Having to do this manuallu is pretty tedious as I try to automate my build and release process via Fastlane and

> I was wondering if anyone managed to solve this with either fastlane
> or scripting?